# How to round all the values in an array to 2 decimal points

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to round the values in my array to 2 decimal points. I understand i can use math.round but will that work for an whole array? Or will i need to write a function to round each value individually.

Comment: If you want to two decimal point for each element in array you can call Math.Round method for eacch element or you are looking for something else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loops!

```
var x = 0;
var len = my_array.length
while(x < len){ 
    my_array[x] = my_array[x].toFixed(2); 
    x++
}
```

And, yes, a while loop is faster here.

Comment: Cheers for that. That did the job. I was just wondering, why is a while loop faster here? I am sat next to a computer logic genius who is adamant that a for loop would be faster?

Comment: I was a little mixed up, you'd be better off with removing `x` and doing `while(len--){ my_array[len] = my_array[len].toFixed(2);}` The method in my answer is 1ms slower than the way in this comment... see: https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a

Comment: Although that `while` loop is still faster than the `for` loop.  But like Knuth said... "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Take care `.toFixed()` method is returning a string to my_array. If you want it to return a float parse it using `parseFloat(my_array[x]).toFixed(2);`

Comment: +1 to Kengham's comment. the given answer converts all elements to strings which can have unintended consequences

Answer (score 20):

This is a great time to use map.

```
// first, let's create a sample array

var sampleArray= [50.2334562, 19.126765, 34.0116677];

// now use map on an inline function expression to replace each element
// we'll convert each element to a string with toFixed()
// and then back to a number with Number()

sampleArray = sampleArray.map(function(each_element){
    return Number(each_element.toFixed(2));
});

// and finally, we will print our new array to the console

console.log(sampleArray);

// output:
[50.23, 19.13, 34.01]
```

So easy! ;)

Comment: Good job this is what i looking for.

Comment: Be careful, as Kegman pointed out, the .toFixed() method is returning a string.

Answer (score 7):

You have to loop through the array. Then, for each element:

- If you want exactely two digits after the comma, use the [`<number>.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.
- Otherwise, use [`Math.round(<number>*100)/100`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Comparison of both methods:

```
Input   .toFixed(2) Math.round(Input*100)/100
 1.00     "1.00"       1
 1.0      "1.00"       1
 1        "1.00"       1
 0        "0.00"       0
 0.1      "0.10"       0.1
 0.01     "0.01"       0.01
 0.001    "0.00"       0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also make use of ES6 syntax

```js
var arr = [1.122,3.2252,645.234234];

arr.map(ele => ele.toFixed(2));
```